# How to get the significant extent of a time series using data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

Given this data:

```
DATE_ID FRACTION
20160922    0
20160929    0
20161006    0
20161013    0
20161020    0
20161027    0.07
20161103    0.22
20161110    0.5
20161117    0.8
20161124    0.95
20161201    1
20161208    1
20161215    1
20170105    1
20170112    1
20170119    1
```

By definition, the significant extent is the interval between the maximum DATE_ID with minimum FRACTION and minimum DATE_ID and maximum FRACTION:

```
20161020    0
20161027    0.07
20161103    0.22
20161110    0.5
20161117    0.8
20161124    0.95
20161201    1
```

I want to do this using only data.table syntax/internals.
Already tried things like:

```
# Retrieve the upper bound of the interval
t[t[FRACTION == 1, .I[which.min(DATE_ID)]]]
```

But it returns relative indexes. I missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get upper bound and lower bound like this:

```r
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("DATE_ID FRACTION
20160922    0
                        20160929    0
                        20161006    0
                        20161013    0
                        20161020    0
                        20161027    0.07
                        20161103    0.22
                        20161110    0.5
                        20161117    0.8
                        20161124    0.95
                        20161201    1
                        20161208    1
                        20161215    1
                        20170105    1
                        20170112    1
                        20170119    1")

# Working with date format can be easier
DT[, DATE_ID := anytime::anydate(DATE_ID)]

# Calculate the bound
lower <- DT[FRACTION == min(FRACTION), max(DATE_ID)]
upper <- DT[FRACTION == max(FRACTION), min(DATE_ID)]

# Filter the table
DT[DATE_ID %between% c(lower, upper)]
#>       DATE_ID FRACTION
#> 1: 2016-10-20     0.00
#> 2: 2016-10-27     0.07
#> 3: 2016-11-03     0.22
#> 4: 2016-11-10     0.50
#> 5: 2016-11-17     0.80
#> 6: 2016-11-24     0.95
#> 7: 2016-12-01     1.00
```

Comment: This solves only part of the problem and do not return the illustrated result.

Comment: You can use this bounds to filter your table. does not work ?